# Indefinite integral convergence

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that this integral converges?
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-kx^2}{1-x^2}} dx\quad\quad 0\leq k<1
$$

**Edit:** fixed typo *dt* -> *dx*

Comment: I assume that you are integrating with respect to x?

Comment: Hi. consider showing a bit of your work on this so far. This way it is easier to help you!

Comment: This is the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind), $E(k)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $f(x):=\sqrt{\frac{1-kx^2}{1-x^2}}$. Then $f$ is well-defined on the open unit interval and non-negative. Since $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$, we only have to show that $\int_{1/2}^1f(x)\mathrm dx$ is convergent. This follows from the convergence of $\int_{1/2}^1\frac 1{\sqrt{1-x}}\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Why does this follow from $\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx$?
Shouldn't it rather be $\int_{1/2}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Comment: Since $(1-kx^2)/(1+x)\overset{x\to 1}{\sim} (1-k)/2$, it's not a problem.